# How to concat two form data in akka scala?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a method which send picture from client to CDN throught FormData. Code:

```
def uploadToCDN(formData: Multipart.FormData): Future[HttpResponse] = {

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

Http().singleRequest(
  HttpRequest(
    method = HttpMethods.POST,
    uri = "http://cdn.example.com",
    entity = formData.toEntity(),
    protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`))
}
```

How I can add **"secret_key": "12345678"** to FormData which I receive from the client?

Comment: you need to implement security for your end point. You can use outh, outh2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Multipart.FormData` is basically made up of its parts. To join two `FormData`s you need to concatenate the formdata parts and create a new instance of `FormData`:

```
val newFormData = 
  Multipart.FormData(
    Source.single(Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("secret_key", "12345678"))
      .concat(originalFormData.parts)
  )
```

See also the [Scaladocs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.5/akka/http/scaladsl/model/Multipart$$FormData.html) of `Multipart.FormData`.

Comment: Thank you very much